# invoking jquery in php loop

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I am new to php,jquery and json.
I am using all of it in my new website.
My problem is i need to divide my html page into 4 parts as divs(north,south,east,west) and display a pie chart in each div, drawn from a jquery/javascript.
I have added a foreach loop for each zone like north,south,east,west.
and i have set the data needed by jquery/php script in session.

But i see that script executes only at the end of for loop and draws the pie chart only in the fourth div.

I want to know the syntax of how i can invoke the script for every iteration of the php loop.
Request your help.

```
          <?php
    $customerSelected = "IBL";//change this to actual selected customer
    $zoneArray = array(1,2,3,4);
    $_SESSION['customerSelected']=$customerSelected;    
    foreach($zoneArray as $zone){

        $_SESSION['zone']=$zone;    

        $quadrantName = '';
        if($zone == 1){
            $quadrantName = 'firstQuadrantNorth';
        }else if($zone == 2){
            $quadrantName = 'secondQuadrantSouth';
        }else if($zone == 3){
            $quadrantName = 'thirdQuadrantEast';                
        }else if($zone == 4){
            $quadrantName = 'fouthQuadrantWest';

        }
        $_SESSION['quadrant']=$quadrantName;
    ?>
    <div id="<?=$zone?>" style="height:250px;width:49.7%;float:left;      border:1px   solid #CCC;">

        <div id="<?=$quadrantName?>" style="min-width:50%; height:100px;text-align:left"></div>
        <script src="scripts/piechartsims.js?v=<?=$cachebuster; ?>"></script>
        <div style="min-width:50%;height:140px;text-align:center;align:center;overflow:auto;">

            <?php
                include('LastCommunicatedInc.php');   
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

`

Comment: You *really* need to improve you overall code.

Comment: I'm **really** confused by this code. Why are there php variables outside of the php tags? I suggest you go take some php tutorials and read a bit about how requests and responses work.

Comment: Moreover, try to at least separate the html template (View) from the code (Model/Controller). This simple paradigm gives you a lot of maintainability.

Comment: I had simply removed the php tags.Now i have added it.WHat i am trying to do here is i have a php loop and at every iteration i will add a set of div tags.and inside each of those div tags i want to invoke the jquery script with current value of  $quadrantName and $zone which is not happening since the script gets executed only at the end of the loop and draws the pie chart in the last quadrant.